# Restoring a FrontBase database

Tags: restore

I have a FrontBase database that I am trying to restore. This is a database system I have no experience up until now so this may be a basic question. I am issuing the following command to restore

```
c:\usr>FrontBase\bin\FrontBase.exe -console -create -restore=c:\usr\B_2017_03_08-20_36_14 MyDB
```

And get the error

```
2017-03-16 11:28:38 FrontBase Server - 8.2.8 64-bit on Windows NT/2000
2017-03-16 11:28:38 Cannot determine keys identity, Wrong magic number - not a backup file
2017-03-16 11:28:38 Failed to restore database from the backup
```

The backup was actually created on a Mac, I am not sure if the format is portable.

If anyone has experience with Frontbase I would love to hear from them, it doesn't seem to be a common DB.

Answer (score 0):

Is the mac and Windows machines running same version of FrontBase? if not you have to export the database to file format and import it:

#### On mac :

```
WRITE ALL OUTPUT(DIR = '<path>', TYPE = 'FrontBase',
CONTENT = TRUE);
```

#### On Windows:

```
script <path>/schema.sql;
```

See more in release note: http://www.frontbase.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/FBWebSite